# Strange behaviour when selecting columns in data.table in r: Only works when string is given directly, not as a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I want to select some columns in a `data.frame`/`data.table`. However there seems to be a strange behaviour:

Create dummy data:

```
df=data.frame(col1=c(1,2),col2=c(11,22),col3=c(111,222))
```

So our `data.frame` looks like

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1   11  111
2    2   22  222
```

Now I define some variables for the column names:

```
col1='col1'
col2='col2'
```

So both `df[,c(col1,col2)]` and `df[,c('col1','col2')]` result in

```
  col1 col2
1    1   11
2    2   22
```

as one would expect.

However if I do the same on the `data.table` (created by `df=data.table(df)`)

```
   col1 col2 col3
1:    1   11  111
2:    2   22  222
```

something strange happens. `df[,c('col1','col2')]` still gets the correct result:

```
   col1 col2
1:    1   11
2:    2   22
```

but `df[,c(col1,col2)]` does not work anymore:

```
[1]  1  2 11 22
```

Why is that?

Comment: *Non-standard evaluation* is the method that many functions (some base, most of dplyr/data.table) take something that looks like a symbol (no quotes) and uses it as if it were one. It can be confusing (to both the programmer/reader as well as the internal functions) when `col1` can refer to both an object in the global environment _and_ (or?) a column in the frame. See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html as a start, and while it does a good job, there are still many other considerations when trying write in it or deal with multiple "dialects" of R (e.g., dplyr vs data.table).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a strange behavior as it is already mentioned in the documenation - `with = FALSE`

```
df[, c(col1, col2), with = FALSE]
```

-output

```
   col1 col2
1:    1   11
2:    2   22
```

According to `?data.table`

> When with=TRUE (default), j is evaluated within the frame of the data.table; i.e., it sees column names as if they are variables. This allows to not just select columns in j, but also compute on them e.g., x[, a] and x[, sum(a)] returns x$a and sum(x$a) as a vector respectively. x[, .(a, b)] and x[, .(sa=sum(a), sb=sum(b))] returns a two column data.table each, the first simply selecting columns a, b and the second computing their sums.

---

Other options are

```
df[, .(col1, col2)]
   col1 col2
1:    1   11
2:    2   22
df[, .SD, .SDcols = c(col1, col2)]
   col1 col2
1:    1   11
2:    2   22
```

Comment: But then it does not work with `data.frames`. However, my real question is: How is it even possible that col1 and 'col1' do not behave the same way, although they are exactly the same thing?!?

Comment: Because environment/scope where is call it is different